# Find Cartesian coordinates of polar curve $r =5\sin(\theta) + 5\cos(\theta)$

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Polar equation of the form $r = 5\sin(\theta) + 5\cos(\theta)$

The Cartesian equation is of the form $(x-A)^2+(y-B)^2 = R^2$

Find $A,B$, and $R$.

Guess: Let $x = R\cos(\theta) + A$ and $y = R\sin(\theta)+B$. Plug them in and get on the left hand side:
$$50\sin^2(\theta)\cos^2(\theta)+25\cos^4(\theta)+25\sin^4(\theta)+50\sin(\theta)\cos^3(\theta)+50\sin^3(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

Plug in the right hand side:

$$R^2 = 25 + 50\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$

Then set the 2 sides equal to each other. It looks as if $R = 5$. 
Not sure how to go about this further.

Comment: hint: multiply the equation by $r$ and use $x = r\cos \theta$ and $y = r \sin \theta$

Comment: so $r^2 = 5x+5y$ ?

Comment: yes, that is right. you still have to complete the squares to find the center and the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

$r = 5\sin \theta + 5\cos \theta,\quad x = r\cos \theta, \quad y = r\sin \theta$

$\Rightarrow r^2 = 5x + 5y\Rightarrow x^2+y^2=5x + 5y\Rightarrow (x-\frac{5}{2})^2+(y-\frac{5}{2})^2=25/2$

Comment: Completing the square, makes much sense!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Notice that

$$5 \sin\theta + 5 \cos\theta = 5\sqrt{2} \sin(\theta + \pi/4)$$

Now $r = 2a\sin\theta$ is a circle of radius $a$ centered at $(0,a)$. Rotate that circle about the origin by $\pi/4$.